# Handling unclosed fmt.Scan listeners

Tags: go

When attempting to cancel a goroutine with context, previous `fmt.Scan` listeners are not closed, requiring future inputs to be sent twice.

I have written a program that attempts to accomplish the following: iterates a list and for each item in the list, reads user input. If there is no input received within 5 seconds, the iteration continues.

The challenge that I've encountered thus far is that when the iteration continues, the reader continues to listen for input (i.e. the goroutine is still running). What I've come to understand is, during the next iteration, when the user provides input, that input is actually handled by the listener of the previous iteration. As such, the user must input two entries, in order for the most recently opened listener to consume the input.

As an example:

```
Item 1

Timeout, moving to next item

Item 2

asdf
qwet
User entered: qwet

Item 3
```

As you can see, `Item 1` timed out and the program continued to `Item 2` where the user then entered two entries, the program accepting the second, `qwet`. My understanding is that `asdf` when to the unclosed listener that was opened in `Item 1`. Something I don't understand really is the behavior where more than one item timed out. I would expect the number of "open listeners" to equal "number of skips", but it always is two.

As an example:

```
Item 1

Timeout, moving to next item
Item 2

Timeout, moving to next item
Item 3

pop
qwe
User entered: qwe
```

Due to two items passed, I would have thought that there would be two "unclosed" listeners and then a third listener open that spawned due to the current (third) iteration.

Here's the code:

```golang
func AnExperiment() {
    items := []string{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"}

    // d := io.ReadCloser()
    // io.Reader()
    // d := io.NopCloser()
    // reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Println(item)

        c := make(chan string)
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
        go func(ctx context.Context) {
            var input string
            // fmt.Scanln(&input)
            fmt.Scan(&input)
            // input, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            // input = strings.TrimSpace(input)

            c <- input
        }(ctx)

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // fmt.Println("Timeout, moving to next item")
            io.WriteString(os.Stdin, "\nTimeout, moving to next item\n")
            // io.WriteString(os.Stdin, "abc\n\n")
            cancel() // Cancel Scanln
        case userInput := <-c:
            // Use input
            fmt.Println("User entered:", userInput)
            cancel() // Cancel Scanln

        }

        // c := make(chan string)
        // go func(iitem string) {
        //  var input string
        //  fmt.Scanln(&input)
        //  fmt.Println(iitem)
        //  c <- input
        // }(item)

        // timeout := time.After(5 * time.Second)
        // select {
        // case userInput := <-c:
        //  fmt.Println("User entered:", userInput)
        // case <-timeout:
        //  fmt.Println("Timeout, moving to next item")
        //  close(c)
        // }
    }
}
```

My current thought was to artificially supply input to `Stdin` to fool the program into believing that input had been received, but that did not work as expected. I ran into the same issue. I acknowledge that there are challenges with closing goroutines and readers as surfaced in [many](https://benjamincongdon.me/blog/2020/04/23/Cancelable-Reads-in-Go/#fnref:1) [articles](https://medium.com/@zombiezen/canceling-i-o-in-go-capn-proto-5ae8c09c5b29).

So, I'm not sure how to solve my current issue, which is to not require two inputs when the timer times out, much less make it idiomatic.

Comment: `fmt.Scan(&input)` does not take / receive a context, and as such, cancelling a context will not (cannot) affect `fmt.Scan()`. You must redesign.